# Custom wp_welcome_panel for every role or custom dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I would love to customized and dumb down my dashboard with custom icons, shortcuts, guides, etc. I can do this already using widgets, but I would like to dare and do something better.

wp_welcome_panel on this regard, is awesome: I can customized it, I can make it show whatever I want but... only administrators can see this. So I was wondering:

1) Can I customize wp_welcome_panel so that every role can actually see it?

2) Can I add some code before the widgets in order to create a custom dashboard header similar to the one in wp_welcome_panel)? I already tried with

```
function mycustomcontent() {
    echo '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
}
add_action('load-index.php', 'mycustomcontent');
```

But... the HTML output is placed before anything (right after the body tag), even pushing down the sidebar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Where is the "Welcome Panel"?

The Wordpress dashboard (which houses the "Welcome Panel") basically is the

```
~/wp-admin/index.php
```

### When does it show?

As you can see when looking at the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/index.php), there's the following check:

```
if ( has_action( 'welcome_panel' ) && current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) )
```

### How to bypass the needed capability? Make it available for everyone!

This means that the minimum role/capability (role names get assigned as capabilities as well), is `edit_theme_options`. Now you can, as *@OlegButuzov* showed in his answer, either hook a callback to the `user_has_cap` filter, or the filter inside [`get_user_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_user_meta/) - acutally a filter inside [`get_metadata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_metadata/) - named

```
apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );
```

Now a callback would look like the following. Make sure it's hook as close to the welcome panel action as possible. `'all_admin_notices'` would be a nice fit.

Make sure that you only trigger this filter callback on the dashboard and only once. Else you'd give a user unwanted capabilities, resulting in users having access to your actual theme settings. I used the **[WCM Current Admin Info](https://github.com/wecodemore/current-admin-info) plugin** to retrieve that data.

```
// Hooking as late as possible
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', 'wpse119694AddCapCheckOverride' );
function wpse119694AddCapCheckOverride()
{
    // Do some check against get_current_screen()
    if ( 'dashboard' !== get_current_screen()->id )
        add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'wpse119694AddEditThemeOptionsCap', 20, 4 );
}

// The callback used to override the cap check
function wpse119694AddEditThemeOptionsCap( $return, $objectId, $metaKey, $single )
{
    // Instantly remove to avoid conflicts later on
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Only for the current user
    if ( wp_get_current_user()->user_id !== $objectId )
        return $return;

    // Only for the 'edit_theme_options' cap
    if ( 'edit_theme_options' === $metaKey )
        return TRUE;

    return $return;
}
```

### Additional: Show the welcome panel always

Users can dismiss the welcome panel. Sometimes we don't want that as we assume that they haven't read our important info/notes or for whatever reason. Note: You'll need to internals yourself.

```
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', 'wpse119694AddCapCheckOverride' );
function wpse119694AddCapCheckOverride()
{
    // Do some check against get_current_screen()
    if ( 'dashboard' !== get_current_screen()->id )
        add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'wpse119694ShowWelcomePanel', 20, 4 );
}

function wpse119694ShowWelcomePanel( $return, $objectId, $metaKey, $single )
{
    // Instantly remove to avoid conflicts later on
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Only for the current user
    if ( wp_get_current_user()->user_id !== $objectId )
        return $return;

    // ALWAYS show the welcome panel
    if ( 'show_welcome_panel' === $metaKey )
    {
        // Implement additional checks in here
        return TRUE;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

### Custom content for the "Welcome Panel"

Now the first thing we need to do is getting rid of the original content. Then we can add our custom content based on a users ID/Name/Role/etc. Therefore we utilize [`wp_get_current_user()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_current_user/), which returns an instance of `WP_User` filled with all data we need.

```
// Hook as close to the welcome panel as possible
add_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wpse119684WelcomePanelContents' );
function wpse119684WelcomePanelContents()
{
    remove_all_actions( current_filter() );

    $userData = wp_get_current_user();

    $html = <<<EOF
<!-- custom HTML -->
EOF;

    // Here you start overriding the previous $html based on user capabilities.
    if ( 'some-check-against' === $userData )
        $html = <<<EOF
<!-- custom HTML for a specific Role/User/etc.
EOF;

    return $html;
}
```

Now you should be able to customize every bit of your "Welcome Panel" for every User/Role/Capability.

### Reference MarkUp

A good reference to start coding your own "Welcome Panel" content for your user is cores default [`wp_welcome_panel()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/74488bdcb01be5e26d71502836e023dca6e2042a/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L1268) function.

```
<div class="welcome-panel-content">

    <h3><?php _e( 'Headline', 'your_textdomain' ); ?></h3>

    <p class="about-description"><?php _e( 'Intro', your_textdomain' ); ?></p>

    <div class="welcome-panel-column-container">

        <div class="welcome-panel-column">
             <h4><?php _e( 'Sub Headline', your_textdomain' ); ?></h4>
             <a class="button button-primary button-hero hide-if-customize" href="<?php echo get_edit_user_link(); ?>">
                 <?php _e( 'Want to complete your profile? :)', 'your_textdomain' ); ?>
             </a>
        </div>

        <div class="welcome-panel-column">
            <?php /* Some more content in another column */ ?>
        </div>

        <div class="welcome-panel-column welcome-panel-last">
            <?php /* The last column */ ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do that.

You can (a) Edit capability from `edit_theme_options` to `read` in wp source code.
or (c) Change (override) capabilty on a fly for wp-admin/index.php for any usertype...

```
 add_filter('user_has_cap', 'se_119694_user_has_cap');
 function se_119694_user_has_cap($capabilities){
 global $pagenow;
      if ($pagenow == 'index.php')
           $capabilities['edit_theme_options'] = 1;
      return $capabilities;
 }
```

My recommendation - do not do a and/or b.

1. You changing core. Its bad.
2. You giving permitions (even on
   homepage of wp-admin) that person don't really need. Its a security
   HOLE.

In this case you can deploy your panel just nead admin_footer action and using jQuery move it to the top

```
add_action('admin_footer-index.php', 'se_119694_admin_footer');

function se_119694_admin_footer(){
    echo '<div style="display:none;" class="welcome-panel" id="my_wellcome_panel">Hi!</div>';
    echo '
        <script>
            jQuery(window).ready(function(){
                jQuery( "#my_wellcome_panel" ).insertAfter( jQuery( ".wrap h2" ) ).css("display", "block");
            });
        </script>
        ';

}
```